# Brezis' Exercise 4.5

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 4.5** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $p\in [1, \infty)$ and $q \in [1, \infty]$.
>
> 1. Prove that the set
>    $$
>    F:=\{f \in L^p (\Omega) \cap L^q (\Omega) : \|f\|_q \le 1\}
>    $$
>    is closed in $L^p (\Omega)$.
> 2. Let $f_n \in L^p (\Omega) \cap L^q (\Omega)$ and $f \in L^p (\Omega)$. Assume $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ and $\|f_n\|_q \le C$ for all $n$. Then $f \in L^r (\Omega)$ for all $r$ between $p$ and $q$ with $r \neq q$.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is correct?

---

**Proof**

1. Let $f_n \in F$ and $f \in L^p (\Omega)$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$. [There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301365/convergence-in-mathcal-l-1-implies-mu-a-e-convergence-for-a-subsequence) a sub-sequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $f_{\varphi (n)} \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. First, we consider the case $q=\infty$. Then $|f_{\varphi (n)}| \le 1$ $\mu$-a.e. for all $n$. By point-wise convergence, $|f| \le 1$ $\mu$-a.e. Hence $\|f\|_{L^\infty} \le 1$ and thus $f \in F$. Second, we consider the case $p \neq \infty$. By [Fatou's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272096/a-detailed-proof-of-fatou-s-lemma),
   $$
   \int |f|^{q} \le \liminf_n \int |f_{\varphi (n)}|^q \le 1.
   $$
   Hence $\|f\|_q \le 1$ and thus $f \in F$. This completes the proof.
2. Let $r$ be between $p$ and $q$ such that $r \neq q$. There is $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ such that
   $$
   \frac{1}{r} = \frac{\alpha}{p} + \frac{1-\alpha}{q}.
   $$
   By [interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality?useskin=vector#Generalization_with_more_than_two_functions),
   $$
   \|f_n-f_m\|_r \le \|f_n-f_m\|_p^\alpha \cdot \|f_n-f_m\|_q^{1-\alpha} \le (2C)^{1-\alpha}  \|f_n-f_m\|_p^\alpha. \tag{1}
   $$
   [There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301365/convergence-in-mathcal-l-1-implies-mu-a-e-convergence-for-a-subsequence) a sub-sequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $f_{\varphi (n)} \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. By $(1)$, the sequence $(f_{\varphi (n)})$ is Cauchy in $L^r (\Omega)$. By definition of [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space?noredirect=1&lq=1), $f_{\varphi (n)} \to f$ in $L^r$. Because $L^r (\Omega)$ is complete, $f_n \to f$ in $L^r$. Notice that Bochner integral [coincides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508736/lesbegue-integral-coincides-with-bochner-integral-if-the-former-is-finite) with Lebesgue integral. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof of 1. is fine but that of 2. could be shortened:

by question 1,$$\|f\|_q\le C.$$
Therefore,
[$$
f\in L^p\cap L^q\subset L^r.$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386381)

Comment: I wonder where $\sigma$-finite is used.

Comment: Actually, all my textbooks only define integration on $\sigma$-finite measures.